# R sprintf dec2hex error

Tags: r, hex, decimal, printf

Running R on linux (see version below output below)
I experience weird behavior with sprintf converting dec to hex. 
Does anybody know what could explain this? (i.e. first conversion works fine, second returns an error regarding numeric):

```
>  sprintf("%x",2109440182)
[1] "7dbb80b6"
>  sprintf("%x",2151028214)
Error in sprintf("%x", 2151028214) :
  invalid format '%x'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             linux-gnu
>   system         x86_64, linux-gnu
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          0.1
>   year           2013
>   month          05
>   day            16
>   svn rev        62743
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>   nickname       Good Sport

Thanks, Michael

Comment: seems that the limit is:> sprintf("%x",2147483647)
[1] "7fffffff"
> sprintf("%x",2147483648)
Error in sprintf("%x", 2147483648) :
  invalid format '%x'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects

Answer (score 3):

gcc : format ‘%x’ expects an argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’.

I guess the number is larger that an unsigned int. Max range in my system is 2147483648,

So this is correct:

```
printf("%x\n", 2147483647);
```